# Proving that the given mapping is well defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We are given a mapping as follows :

\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi:\hspace{25pt}\ \Bbb{Z}/mn\Bbb{Z}\ &\longrightarrow&\ (\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z})\times (\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}):\\
k\mod(mn) &\longmapsto&\ (k\mod m,k\mod n),
\end{eqnarray*}

we need to prove that this map is well defined.

To prove that a function $f(x)$ is well defined , we pick two elements from the domain , say $x$ and $y$ , and we say , $x=y$ , and we somehow prove that $f(x)=f(y)$.

So I took $k_1 ,k_2 \in \Bbb{Z}/mn\Bbb{Z}$ , and let , $k_1 =k_2$.

Then $k_1 \equiv k_2 \pmod{mn}$ and so $k_1 - k_2\equiv0 \pmod{mn}$, but couldn't proceed further. Could anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: Ultimately , we have to prove that this mapping is indeed an isomorphism.. @Servaes

Comment: And when you arrive at $k_1-k_2=0\pmod{mn}$, what do you intend to prove?

Comment: From this " $k_1−k_2=0 \mod{mn}$" , I somehow wanted , $k_1 \mod{m} = k_2 \mod {m}$ and  $k_1 \mod{n} = k_2 \mod {n}$ .. @Servaes

Comment: Great! Try to show this using the answer I have given below :)

Comment: I was trying to prove that this " $\phi$ " is onto.. Is this the correct way ? 

Let $y = ( a \mod{m} , a \mod{n}) \in Z_m \times Z_n$ where $a \in Z$ ,

Since , $ a \mod{m} \in Z_m$ & $ a \mod{n} \in Z_n$ ,=> $ a \mod{m} < m$ and  $a \mod{n} < n$ , => $a \mod{mn} < mn$ , and hence $a \mod{mn} \in Z_{mn}$ .. ? @Servaes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of abuse of notation, a fact you might want to use is the following:
$$x\equiv0\pmod{mn}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad mn\mid x\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad n\mid x\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad x\equiv0\pmod{n}.$$

Comment: Isn't that true only when gcd(m,n) = 1 ?

Comment: No; consider what $mn\mid x$ means. It means $x$ is a multiple of $mn$. Then it is certainly a multiple of $n$.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks a lot !